# Reference error: import jQuery in bootstrap toggle while using typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, import, referenceerror

I am  using typescript AMD module.

In my **app.ts** I got these imports:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';
//import 'bootstrap-toggle';
```

My code got jQuery, bootstrap and bootstrap-toggle functions.
If I have commented out the bootstrap toggle library like the upper code shown my app works fine and don't show me errors.

But without my bootstrap-toggle library I can't use my functions of this library.

If I commend it in, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (in bootstrap-toggle.js)

My **bootstrap-toggle.js** file is also using jQuery with this function:

```
function ($) {
...
}(jQuery);
```

I think, the problem is that I am including my jQuery only for my **app.js** and not in my bootstrap-toggle.js

But how I can define a import globally? I wont import jQuery on this way in my bootstrap-toggle.js file because it is a tool from [here](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) and not written by mine.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Sony

Comment: One problem is that you're only importing `$` from jQuery, so the symbol `jQuery` itself is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I also can import jQuery from 'jquery' in my app.js, but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. The typescript AMD module uses require JS, so it has to set up a require js config file like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: { 
        app: 'app',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap-toggle" : ["jquery"]
    }
});
```

If jQuery should be available for bootstrap toggle it requires the shim option in the require config.